# QML: How to change the colour on the image?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

We are having a transparent image and we want the colour of that image according to the theme selected.

Is it possible in Qt or QML ?

Comment: Do you mean that the transparent parts of the image should look like they're coloured?

Comment: Yes, they should be coloured to red if we select Red theme,or blue if we select that as theme. I tried with Qt, the results were not that good so now we trying to get the requirement in QML.

Comment: I'm not sure I did understand your problem... My 2-cent solution is to just put your transparent image over a coloured element (like a Rectangle)